# Is it thread safe using variables between closures in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, thread-safety, closures, protected

I was reading an [article](http://www.nmjenkins.com/2010/04/privateprotected-without-using-caller.html) about private/protected members "emulation"
with javascript ( i know it's not a *best practice* but it's for *research purpose* )

For example, in this code we've:

```js
var Class = (function() { // Open closure

var caller = null;

//[...]

var mayAccessWrapped = false;
function wrapmethod(method) {

    mayAccessWrapped = true;
    if (method.__getWrappedMethod) {
        method = method.__getWrappedMethod();
    }
    mayAccessWrapped = false;

    var wrapped = function wrapper() {
        var prevCaller = caller;
        caller = wrapper;
        var returns;
        try {
            returns = method.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        finally {
            caller = prevCaller;
        }
        return returns;
    };
    wrapped.__getWrappedMethod = function() {
        if (mayAccessWrapped) { return method; }
        throw "Error: only the wrapping function may access the wrapped method";
    }
    return wrapped;
}
 
//[...]

return Class;

})(); // End Class closure
```

"wrapped" method is used multiple times from same object and it uses caller variable to "inject" informations about the "caller" with "called" method ( [alternative to deprecated arguments.callee](http://www.nmjenkins.com/2010/04/private-and-protected-fields-in.html)).

But, in a concurrent scope, is this way thread safe? Is it possible that another method can change the value of **caller** variable invalidating data consistency?

Comment: Javascript does not have threads.

Comment: Not fully true, it depends from engine: http://jxcore.com/home/

Comment: From the documentation of the engine you linked to: *"Every instance in JXcore are called a sub-instance. The sub-instance is completely separated from the main instance and from the other sub-instances, because they all run in different V8′s contexts/isolates. It means that they cannot share or have common objects, variables etc. directly."*

Answer (score 1):

If you *literally* mean "thread-safe," I think that the first question must be ... is your JavaScript interpreter thread-safe?  Does it *allow* two or more threads to own their own interpreter-context?  Is it *designed* with the necessary internal mutual-exclusion mechanisms to permit two or more threads to simultaneously access an interpreter's internal context/state? (And if so, are you using these facilities in *exactly* the prescribed way?)

If not, your program is quite certain to crash.  The threads will wind up scribbling on the interpreter's internal state and "down she goes."